# How to run all threads in sequence as static with out using opemMP for?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm new to openMP and multi-threading.

I have been given a task to run a method as static, dynamic, and guided without using OpenMPfor loop which means I cant use scheduled clauses.!

I could create parallel threads with parallel and could assign loop iterations to threads equally
but how to make it static and dynamic(1000 block) and guided?

```
void static_scheduling_function(const int start_count,
                                const int upper_bound,
                                int *results)
{
    int i, tid, numt;
    
    #pragma omp parallel private(i,tid) 
    {
        int from, to;
        
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        numt = omp_get_num_threads();
        from = (upper_bound / numt) * tid;
        to = (upper_bound / numt) * (tid + 1) - 1;
        
        if (tid == numt - 1)
            to = upper_bound - 1;
        
        for (i = from; i < to; i++)
        {
            //compute one iteration (i)
            int start = i;
            int end = i + 1;
            compute_iterations(start, end, results);
        }
    }
}


======================================
For dynamic i have tried something like this

void chunk_scheduling_function(const int start_count, const int upper_bound, int* results) {


       int numt, shared_lower_iteration_counter=start_count;

    for (int shared_lower_iteration_counter=start_count; shared_lower_iteration_counter<upper_bound;){

            #pragma omp parallel shared(shared_lower_iteration_counter)
            {

            int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
            int from,to;
            int chunk = 1000;



            #pragma omp critical
            {
            from= shared_lower_iteration_counter;                                      // 10, 1010
            to = ( shared_lower_iteration_counter + chunk );                           // 1010, 
            shared_lower_iteration_counter = shared_lower_iteration_counter + chunk;    // 1100  // critical is important while incrementing shared variable which decides next iteration

            }


            for(int i = from ; (i < to && i < upper_bound ); i++) {  // 10 to 1009 , i< upperbound prevents other threads from executing call
                int start = i;
                int end = i + 1;
                compute_iterations(start, end, results);
            }



        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a university assignment (and a very good one IMO), I will not provide the complete solution, instead I will provide what you should be looking for.

The `static` scheduler looks okey; Notwithstanding, it can be improved by taking into account the `chunk` size as well.

For the `dynamic` and `guided` schedulers, they can be implemented by using a variable (let us name it *`shared_iteration_counter`*) that will be marking the current loop iteration that should pick up next by the threads. Therefore, when a thread needs to request a new task to work with (*i.e.,* a new loop iteration) it queries that variable for that. In pseudo code would look like the following:

```
int thread_current_iteration = shared_iteration_counter++;

while(thread_current_iteration < MAX_SIZE)
{
      // do work
      thread_current_iteration = shared_iteration_counter++;
}
```

The pseudo code is assuming `chunk` size of `1` (*i.e.*, `shared_iteration_counter++`) you will have to adapt to your use-case. Now, because that variable will be **shared among threads**, and **every thread will be updating it**, you need to ensure [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) during the updates of that variable. Fortunately, OpenMP offers means to achieve that, for instance, using `#pragma omp critical`, explicitly locks, and `atomic operations`. The latter is the better option for your use-case:

```
#pragma omp atomic
shared_iteration_counter = shared_iteration_counter + 1;
```

For the [guided scheduler](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/openmp-loop-scheduling.html):

> Similar to dynamic scheduling, *but the chunk size starts off large and
> decreases to better handle load imbalance between iterations.* The
> optional chunk parameter specifies them minimum size chunk to use. By
> default the chunk size is approximately loop_count/number_of_threads.

In this case, not only you have to guarantee `mutual exclusion` of the variable that will be used to count the current loop iteration to be pick up by threads, but also guarantee `mutual exclusion` of the `chunk` size variable, since it also changes.

Without given it way too much bear in mind that you may need to considered how to deal with edge-cases such as your current `thread_current_iteration= 1000` and your `chunks_size=1000` with a `MAX_SIZE=1500`. Hence, `thread_current_iteration + chunks_size > MAX_SIZE`, but there is still `500` iterations to be computed.